# How to fix wrong Request file routing

Tags: laravel

i am biginner in laravel,and make a request file by :

php artisan make:request taskRequest

in controller define store function:

```
 public function store(taskRequest $request)
    {

    }
```

and in web.php routing by Resource method :

```
Route::resource('/taskmanager/tasks', tasksController::class);
```

and in controller and Request add the target class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

but i recive this error:

Target class [App\Http\Controllers\taskRequest] does not exist.

Even though I defined the target correctly, it addresses from the controllers path
taskController and taskRequest Each is in its own folder

Comment: In your controller, add `App\Http\Controllers\taskRequest` below namespace and top of class TaskController

Comment: but taskController and taskRequest Each is in its own folder

Comment: taskController in controllers path and taskRequest in Requests path(folder)

Comment: So use the correct path then

Comment: i adding use App\Http\Requests\taskRequest; to taskRequest but not work at all

Comment: Add it to your controller - the one that wants to use your taskRequest.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `TaskController` does not recognize `taskRequest`. Add `use App\Http\Requests\taskRequest` in your TaskController( Below namespace and top of `class TaskController`. This should recognize your `taskRequest` now.

TaskController.php (Should be inside App\Http\Controllers)

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

... # other use class
use App\Http\Requests\taskRequest;
... # other use class

class TaskController extends Controller
{ 
    public function store(taskRequest $request)
    {

    }

    ... # other methods
}
```

taskRequest.php: (Should be inside App\Http\Requests, case sensitive too)

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Requests;

class taskRequest extends FormRequest
{
}
```

Comment: but taskController is in controllers folder and taskRequest in request folder

Comment: add use App\Http\Requests\taskRequest; to taskRequest but not work at all

Comment: @brombeer, my bad was copy pasting my code.

Comment: Also make sure that you use that filename `taskRequest` and inside the code `class taskRequest` matches. This is case sensitive.